# CXF test failing SelectChannelConnector exception on Unit Test

Tags: json, spring, maven, jetty, cxf

Hi I am facing issues(test cases failures) while upgrading my project libraries with java8:

```
CXF failing with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext caused by Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdeQueryRs': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/nio/SelectChannelConnector exception on Unit Test
```

getting errors while maven build:

Failed tests: Stack traces

```
  [main][2015-12-14 11:56:38,100] o.a.c.j.u.AnnotationUtils                WARN  Method generateAICFile in com.flintenergy.fief.jde.db.rs.JdePartyQueryServiceImpl has no JAX-RS Path or HTTP Method annotations
     [main][2015-12-14 11:56:38,167] o.a.c.t.h.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory   INFO  Could not load or start org.eclipse.management.MBeanContainer.  Jetty JMX support will not be enabled: org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer
     [main][2015-12-14 11:56:38,185] o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext        WARN  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
     [main]org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdeQueryRs': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/nio/SelectChannelConnector
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117) [junit-rt.jar:na]
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234) [junit-rt.jar:na]
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74) [junit-rt.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.getHTTPConnectorFactory(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:651) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.retrieveListenerFactory(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:640) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.finalizeConfig(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:692) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.getOrCreate(JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.java:121) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.createJettyHTTPServerEngine(JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.java:268) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.retrieveEngine(JettyHTTPDestination.java:121) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.finalizeConfig(JettyHTTPDestination.java:154) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(HTTPTransportFactory.java:281) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:84) ~[cxf-core-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:63) ~[cxf-core-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:170) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1641) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        ... 61 common frames omitted
    [2015-12-14 11:56:38,259] o.s.t.c.TestContextManager               ERROR Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@2938127d] to prepare test instance [com.flintenergy.fief.jde.db.rs.JdeQueryServiceCxfTest@15b12bc5]
     [main]java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117) [junit-rt.jar:na]
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234) [junit-rt.jar:na]
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74) [junit-rt.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdeQueryRs': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/nio/SelectChannelConnector
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/nio/SelectChannelConnector
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.getHTTPConnectorFactory(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:651) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.retrieveListenerFactory(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:640) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.finalizeConfig(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:692) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.getOrCreate(JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.java:121) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.createJettyHTTPServerEngine(JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.java:268) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.retrieveEngine(JettyHTTPDestination.java:121) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.finalizeConfig(JettyHTTPDestination.java:154) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.redhat-620133.jar:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
        at
```

my dependencies:

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ fief-jde-svcs-db ---
[INFO] com.flintenergy.fief.jde:fief-jde-svcs-db:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.flintenergy.fief:fief-specs:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.flintenergy.fief:fief-resources:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.flintenergy.fief.jde:fief-extension-jde:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mdw360.jde:jde-ext-client:jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mdw360:mdw360-core:jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:test
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-management:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:jar:3.1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:jar:3.0.0-milestone1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.mina:mina-core:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- rhino:js:jar:1.7R2:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.oauth.core:oauth-provider:jar:20100527:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.oauth.core:oauth:jar:20100527:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.0.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-policy:jar:2.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings-wss10:jar:2.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings-wsu10:jar:2.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings-wss11:jar:2.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings-wssc:jar:2.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:tests:2.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax:jar:2.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.mdw360:mdw360-spring:jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.ibm.as400:jt400:jar:7.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.beanio:beanio:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.mdw360:mdw360-test:jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:test
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:test
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:test
[INFO] +- com.flintenergy.fief:fief-test-resources:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.160:test
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:jar:2.0M10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.easytesting:fest-util:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] +- org.easytesting:fest-guava-assert:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-junit-adaptor:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-java-aspects:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] |     +- ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-java-adaptor-api:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-java-annotations:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-model:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  |     +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  |     \- ru.yandex.qatools.properties:properties-loader:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |     |  |        \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] \- com.github.detro.ghostdriver:phantomjsdriver:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.json:json:jar:20080701:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- net.java.dev.jna:platform:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-android-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.12:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.2.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.12:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.18:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.9:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:jar:8.1.9.v20130131:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-iphone-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.webbitserver:webbit:jar:0.4.14:compile
[INFO]    |     \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.5.2.Final:compile
[INFO]    \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]       +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.48:compile
[INFO]       +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.48:compile
[INFO]       +- mx4j:mx4j-tools:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.9:compile
[INFO]       +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:jetty-repacked:jar:7.6.1:compile
[INFO]       +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]       \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO]
```

My Unit test:

```
public class JdeQueryServiceCxfTest extends AbstractTestCxf {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdeQueryServiceClient")
    private QueryService ws;
    @Test
    public void testStatus() throws Exception {
        log.info("Status test starting");
        String status = ws.status();
        Assert.assertEquals(AuthenticationService.STATUS_OK, status);
        log.info("Status test finished");
    }
```

If you're still here, thanks for reading.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty 9.x does not have `org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector`.

That class is from a long ago Jetty 8 (and earlier), which are now EOL (End of Life)

The move to HTTP/2 and Servlet 3.1 overhauled the entire connector architecture in Jetty.

Apache CXF 3.1.4 (non-redhat version) supports Jetty 9.2.11.

You also have 3 different version of Jetty present in your dependency tree.

```
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:test
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:test
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:test
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.3.5.v20151012:test
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:jar:8.1.9.v20130131:compile
```

Fix those dependencies to only use 9.2.11 (as that's what supported by Apache CXF 3.1.4).  Since you start Jetty from Apache CXF, you have to use what Apache CXF expects (don't upgrade or downgrade the version)

Comment: Thanks I made the changes .Now I am getting one and only test class failed different errors: